# How do I transform a non-linear relationship to make it linear?

Tags: r, data-transformation

I have some data which follow a nonlinear relationship like that displayed in the plot below. The non-linear data do not come directly from the explicit function written in the code below!

```
x1 <- seq(-1,-0.0001,len=500)
x2 <- seq(0.0001,1,len=500)
df <- data.frame(x=c(x1,x2),y=c(1-0.0001^x1,0.0001^(-x2)-1))
plot(df[,1],df[,2],type="p")
```

[image]

Given that there are negative values in both `x` and `y`, how do I transform such data? Is this even possible? If this is possible, what are the repercussions of such transformation?

Comment: The main repercussion is of using transforms fit for your purpose is that they lack a neat verbal interpretation.

Comment: Why do you want to transform this data?

Comment: If the data here are not your data, it may well be that a transformation that linearizes *this* one may fail to linearize yours.

Comment: To add to Glen_b's point and to [paraphrase Tolstoy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anna_Karenina_principle), "Linear functions are all alike, each non-linear function is non-linear in its own way."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In this problem you have an explicit functional relationship between the two variables:

$$y = \text{sgn}(x) (10^{4|x|}-1).$$

You can obtain a linear relationship between transformed variables by using:

$$\text{sgn}(y) \log_{10}(1+|y|) = 4x.$$

Comment: Sorry @Ben, thanks for your answer first of all. I should have mentioned in my question that the non-linear data do not come directly from the explicit function I wrote above. I just used the explicit function to express the kind of non-linear relationship that my data is exhibiting.

Comment: $\text{sign}(y) \log (1 + |y|)$ is an easy way to keep the sign. Other transformations that arise for this kind of data include cube roots, other odd integer roots and inverse hyperbolic sine.

Comment: @Nick: Edited to do this.

Comment: In some literature that transformation is called neglog. The term is ugly (and not mine) but easy to search for.